# how to debug PHP on xampp

Tags: php, netbeans, xampp, xdebug, php-ini

my IDE is netbeans 8.2 and iam using xampp 3.2.1

what am i doing wrong ?

this is my php.ini file

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

this is the settings on netbeans:
[image]

Comment: you can use `FirePHP` too, to debug you PHP. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check [this wiki page](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug). You are missing at least port and mode configuration in the php.ini file:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Comment: And what error message do you see? Is there anything in IDE log (http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqLogMessagesFile)?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line if missing, in your php.ini file

;extension=php_xdebug.dll